# Need help installing fiona and geopandas for python in Windows 10 - getting can't load requested DLL error

Tags: python, pip, geopandas, osgeo, fiona

I am trying to install fiona and geopandas for python on Windows 10 and keep running into an error "ERROR 1: Can't load requested DLL".

I know this question is similar to other questions that have been asked, but I have followed the steps in multiple answers and tutorials and still can't seem to get this to work.

The closest I got was using the steps outlined in this tutorial : https://geoffboeing.com/2014/09/using-geopandas-windows/

and are summarized as follows:

1. installed the .whl files for rtree, pyproj, shapely, gdal, geopandas, fiona from https://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/

   - Rtree-0.8.3-cp37-cp37m-win_amd64.whl
   - pyproj-2.2.1-cp37-cp37m-win_amd64.whl
   - GDAL-3.0.0-cp37-cp37m-win_amd64.whl
   - geopandas-0.5.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl
   - Fiona-1.8.6-cp37-cp37m-win_amd64.whl
   - Shapely-1.6.4.post2-cp37-cp37m-win_amd64.whl
2. navigated to download folder and used pip install to install GDAL wheel
3. added the osgeo path to my windows user Path environment variable

[image: environment variable screen]

4. used pip install to install remaining wheels (geopandas last), everything installed without errors
5. As a check, I ran `gdalinfo --help-general` and get the following output:

[image: gdalinfo output]

This is where I get the "ERROR 1: Can't load requested DLL:" error. It says it cannot find the specified module "ogr_FileGDB.dll". The weird thing is, that .dll is actually in the location that it is looking in???

[image: dll location]

Also, in python shell, when trying to import fiona or geopandas I get the following errors:

[image: import errors]

This is beyond my level of troubleshooting...would really appreciate if anyone could get this thing working for me!!!!

FYI - running Python 3.7.3, Windows 10, pip is updated.

Lastly and potentially important (not sure how it plays in?) I already have a GDAL_DATA system variable defined, and also (maybe incorrectly?) also tried adding the osgeo path to my system path variable:

[image: system environment variable]

Comment: Is there any reason why you don't want to use Conda? Installing everything from `conda-forge` should make your life much easier.

Comment: Fiona depends on `GDAL‑2.4.1`. It is not compatible with GDAL 3.

Comment: `ogr_FileGDB.dll` requires [`FileGDB_API_1_5_1`](https://github.com/Esri/file-geodatabase-api/tree/master/FileGDB_API_1.5.1), or just delete the dll if you don't plan to use it

Comment: `GDAL_DATA` should point to `...\Lib\site-packages\osgeo\data\gdal`. It's best not to define the environment variables manually.

Comment: @cgohlke Thanks very much.. I ended up just uninstallaing GDAL and installing the version you mentioned and it worked fine.

Comment: I can't install fiona after installing gdal from the wheel and adding it to PATH. The only difference I see is that I'm trying to install it in a pipenv environment so my path is `C:\Users\myuser\.virtualenvs\myenv\Lib\site-packages\osgeo`. The stack trace is VERY long and is hard to find any meaningful information of whats going wrong. Please help @cgohlke as you seem to be the one who makes all windows geopandas installations possible without conda

Comment: `Building wheel for gdal (setup.py): started
  Building wheel for gdal (setup.py): finished with status 'error'
  Running setup.py clean for gdal
Failed to build gdal
Installing collected packages: six, click, munch, gdal, cligj, click-plugins, certifi, attrs, Fiona
  Attempting uninstall: gdal
    Found existing installation: GDAL 2.4.1
    Uninstalling GDAL-2.4.1:
      Successfully uninstalled GDAL-2.4.1
    Running setup.py install for gdal: started
    Running setup.py install for gdal: finished with status 'error'
  Rolling back uninstall of GDAL`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was using a GDAL version that was not compatible with Fiona and subsequently causing issues with geopandas.

I uninstalled GDAL 3 and installed GDAL 2.4.1 and it worked fine, as cgohlke suggested.

Answer (score 0):

Install `fiona` with `conda`, then that will solve the `GDAL` problem. `pip install geopandas` should work after that.